Running Executables with Input in Parallel in Python
I have a program that requires me to run multiple executables and I would like to increase performance by running these in parallel.
My base code looks something like this:
import subprocess

def run_exe(input_command):
    p = subprocess.Popen('example.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(bytes(input_command,'utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_exe('task_1')
    run_exe('task_2')

I would like to either multithread this or multi-process it but when I do it doesn't work. I checked stdout and it looks like the input_command sent by p.communicate isn't being acknowledged (stdout has an "awaiting input" message). I saw a vague reference online that mentioned that p.communicate might only work properly on the main process but the poster didn't have any additional details for why or any potential workarounds. This is an example of the multi-thread code I want to implement:
import subprocess
import threading

def run_exe(input_command):
    p = subprocess.Popen('example.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.communicate(bytes(input_command,'utf-8'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t1 = threading.Thread(run_exe,('task_1',))
    t2 = threading.Thread(run_exe,('task_2',))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

But as mentioned above, the executable isn't receiving the input correctly.

Does it work if you use multi-processing instead of multi-threading?

@Barmar no,  I get the same result with multi-processing.

I'm not sure why it's not working. But you don't need threads. Just change your code so you don't want for each subprocess to finish before going to the next one. Do all the subprocess.Popen() calls, write the command to their p.stdin. Put all the processes in a list and call p.wait() on each of them. Google "python multiple subprocess in parallel" and you'll find several previous questions about it.

threading.Thread(run_exe,('task_1',)) -> threading.Thread(None, run_exe, args=('notepad',)), first argument is deprecated and should be None, and third argument is not args, so you need that explicitly.

Or threading.Thread(target=run_exe, args=('task_1',)).

I suggest using concurrent.futures, which is a wrapper and is simpler than using threading directly.
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import subprocess


def run_exe(input_command: str):
    process = subprocess.run(
        ["example.exe"],
        input=input_command,
        text=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    return process.stdout


def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format="%(asctime)s | %(levelname)-8s | %(threadName)-24s | %(message)s",
        datefmt="%H:%M:%S",
    )
    logging.info("Start")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        output = [(arg, executor.submit(run_exe, arg)) for arg in ["task_1", "task_2"]]

    for arg, future in output:
        logging.info("%s --> %s", arg, future.result())

    logging.info("End")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
11:16:12 | INFO     | MainThread               | Start
11:16:15 | INFO     | MainThread               | task_1 --> Output for task_1
11:16:15 | INFO     | MainThread               | task_2 --> Output for task_2
11:16:15 | INFO     | MainThread               | End

Notes

I use subprocess.run(), which is highly recommended over Popen

Set input=input_command is how I send text to the process' stdin
Set text=True so I don't have to encode/decode the input/output


I started a thread pool with ThreadPoolExecutor, I can also use ProcessPoolExecutor as they have the same interface

output is a list of (input, future)
When I exit the with statement, I can be sure that all tasks are completed



